# cmake set UseOfAtl for visual studio generated files

Tags: cmake, mfc, atl

I need to set options in cmake to generate these entries in visual studio .vcxproj file

```
<UseOfMfc>false</UseOfMfc>
<UseOfAtl>Static</UseOfAtl>
```

Cmake supports MFC via CMAKE_MFC_FLAG which translates into a "UseOfMFC" entry in the generated visual studio project files.
So my question is how to set UseOfAtl in the cmake file?

The only workaround I found was to change the cmake sorces.
Is there any chances to not change cmake sources?

Comment: Well you can see that's not in cmake source so I guess it would be better to post that question to cmake discourse. Also ATL (and MFC) has kinda lost its lovers these days so not sure it would be top of their priority anyway. But you can customize msbuild using external files (that you can integrate in cmake) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory